# Docker: Where are my context files after I create a container from Dockerfile?

Tags: dockerfile

I have the below file hierarchy

```
├── my_project
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   └── my_files
│       ├── test.py
│       └── main.py
```

and the Dockerfiles is:

```
FROM alpine:latest
MAINTAINER JohnSmith "johnhdf@gmail.com"
```

I have created an image under the `my_project` folder by:
`docker build -t my_container .`
     and then started a container by running:
`docker run -it <image id> /bin/sh`

However, in the container, I could not find the folder `my_files` and `main.py` / `test.py`

Am I missing some steps? I thought running `docker build` with `.` would load the files in the current directory into the container somewhere, but I'm not sure where.

Comment: Did you `ADD` or `COPY` the files you would like to run in docker? Is your docker file just the 2 lines as shown above? Could add the entire file please? If that's the file you have you may want to create a `WORKDIR` and `ADD` all the required files to it. You may also want to look at `VOLUMES` in docker.

Comment: Yes, this is the entire dockerfile.  I thought `.` in the `docker build` command would package all files in the current directory into the container so I did not use any `COPY` or `ADD`.  What is the point of using `.` in `docker build` then?

Comment: The "build context" is the source for `COPY` and `ADD` instructions; you can't `COPY` anything into an image that's not in the context directory, but absent a `COPY` nothing automatically gets copied into an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mount the folder in your server with the folder in the container. For that, update your run command as follows.

```
docker run -it -v <fullpath>/my_project/my_files:/root/my_files <image id> /bin/sh
```

So that you can see all files in **my_files** in the **/root/my_files** of your container

Comment: Thank you.  follow-up question:  I thought `.` in the `docker build` command would package all files in the current directory into the container so I did not use any `COPY` or `ADD`. What is the point of using . in `docker build` then?

Comment: `.` specify the context path. Means the Dockerfile and its dependencies. If you are in my_project folder, you can build the image with `docker build -t my_container .` If you are in the parent folder of my_project, then you can build the image with `docker build -t my_container ./my_project/`

Comment: This does not add any files to the image.  It happens to run a container with the current directory mounted over some part of the container filespace, but that's not usually how you'd want to package application code in an image.